# CodeIgniter Pagination only shows fixed numbers (1,2,3)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-pagination

I did a pagination which pass the `data` through `ajax` from the view. in case it skip the `$config['uri_segemnt']` . Here I set the total number of rows and `per page` manually.
the function creates all the `html tags` and `pagination tags` and append them to `view`. It is working but the pagination shows only three numbers every time.  Seems to be the pagination not calculate the `total row count`,how can I solve this?
Here is my function and the view.

PHP controller function

```
public function getVoucherajax() {
        if (!empty($_POST)) {
            $offset = $_POST['limit'];
            $selecttedList = $_POST['listID'];
        } else {
            $offset = 0;
        }

        $count = $this->getTotalOCount($selecttedList);
        $voucherCount = $count[0]['vcount'];
        //$limit = perpage

        $allvouchers = $this->voucher_model->getallvouchers($this->perPage(), $offset, $selecttedList);

        $config = array();
        $config['total_rows'] = 56;
        $config['per_page'] = 10;


////bootstrap config for pagination
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        echo 'Row Count -'.' '.$config['total_rows'];
        $links = $this->pagination->create_links();

//        print_r($allvouchers);
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="50">id</th>
                        <th width="150">Created</th>
                        <th width="150">Valid From</th>
                        <th width="150">Valid To</th>
                        <th width="100">Type</th>
                        <th width="100">State</th>
                    </tr>  
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($allvouchers['allVouchers'] as $rows) {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['id'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['created'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['validfrom'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['validto'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['type'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['state'] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <?php echo $links; ?>
        </div> 

        <?php
    }
```

view

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        loadList()
        loadVoucher()
        pagination()

        function loadList() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/loadListsAjax",
            }).done(function ($data) {
                $("#list").html($data);
            });
        }

        function loadVoucher() {
            $("#list").change(function () {
                var listID = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/getVoucherajax",
                    data: {limit: 0,listID: listID}
                }).done(function($data){
                    $("#contents").html($data);
                });
            });

        }


        function pagination(){
        $(document).on("click",".pagination li a",function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
//            alert('sddsd');
            var segment = $(this).attr("data-ci-pagination-page");
            if(!segment){
                segment = 0;
            }

            var list = $("#list").val();
//            alert(list);
//
            $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/getVoucherajax",
                    data: {limit: segment,listID: list}
                }).done(function($data){
                    $("#contents").html($data);
                });

        });
        }


    });
</script>



<div class="col-sm-9">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select id="list" class="form-control">

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="contents" class="row" style="padding-top: 100px;">



    </div>
```

[image]

At the top of the image, it shows the `query` and the `total row count.`

Comment: It's likely you only see three because by default the pagination class is set to display 2 links (2 links either side of the current page). This can be changed via `$config['num_links'] `. If you are on page 2, does it still only show upto page 3?

Comment: yes, but according to the `total number of rows` it will change.. but here it is not happening.

Comment: Even if there are 10000 rows, when you are on page one it will always show 2 links either side of the current page. In your screenshot your on page 1, so it will show [1, 2, 3]. If you were on page 6 it would show [4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: unfortunately it is not happening. I removed some `configs` because here sending them through` ajax` that is only thing I change here in the `pagination config.`

Comment: unfortunately it is not happening. I removed some `configs` ( `$config["base_url"]` ,`$config["uri_segment`"]) because  `$config["base_url"]` and `$config["uri_segment` not required because of `ajax`. here I set them manually as well. as you mention here if I reduce per page count result should change.. but not happening

Comment: If thats the case, I imagine you will have to extend the Codeigniter pagination class to remove/change references to `$this->uri_segment`, otherwise it will use that value to determine the current page number